# Include command output to json

Tags: json, bash, curl

Trying to send a weekly overview of the backup size from a bash script which does a curl to send a message.

```
echo $(curl -s \
  -X POST \
  --user "aasdfasdfbc:4adgadfgsdfg" \
  https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "FromEmail":"noreply@bashdrsh.li",
    "FromName":"Backup Notification",
    "Recipients": [ 
      {
      "Email":"back.upper@bashdrsh.li"
      }
    ],
    "Subject":"['"$host"'] Backup overview",
    "Text-part":"Backup on '"$host"' weekly overview\n\n '"$(find /tmp/backup/2017-07-12/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -exec ls -hls {} \; | awk '{  printf "%-40s %30s\n", $10, $6 }')"'\n"
  }')
```

But the find command always returns with this response

```
  find: paths must precede expression: globals-only.7z
  Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec|time] [path...] [expression]
  {
      "FromEmail":"noreply@bashdrsh.li",
      "FromName":"Backup Notification",
      "Recipients": [ 
        {
        "Email":"back.upper@bashdrsh.li"
        }
      ],
      "Subject":"[MYLOCAL] Backup overview",
      "Text-part":"Backup on MYLOCAL weekly overview\n\n \n"
    }
```

Running the find command on command line it returns everything as expected

```
# find /tmp/backup/2017-07-12/ -name '*.7z' -exec ls -hls {} \; | awk '{  printf "%-40s %30s\n", $10, $6 }'
/tmp/backup/2017-07-12/globals-only.7z                             7.3K
/tmp/backup/2017-07-12/auth.7z                                      759
```

How can I include a nice formatted table into the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the same `find` expression in `curl` invocation and later on command line. Also, no need for `ls` & `awk`.

Try replacing your complete command substitution with:

```
find /tmp/backup/2017-07-12/ -name '*.7z' -printf "%-40P %30s\n"
```

For readability, you can store that into a variable, and use like:

```
output=$(find /tmp/backup/2017-07-12/ -name '*.7z' -printf "%-40P %30s\n")
echo $(curl -s \
  -X POST \
  --user "aasdfasdfbc:4adgadfgsdfg" \
  https://api.mailjet.com/v3/send \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "FromEmail":"noreply@bashdrsh.li",
    "FromName":"Backup Notification",
    "Recipients": [ 
      {
      "Email":"back.upper@bashdrsh.li"
      }
    ],
    "Subject":"['"$host"'] Backup overview",
    "Text-part":"Backup on '"$host"' weekly overview\n\n '"$output"'\n"
  }')
```

Comment: but then the email with the overview is like : Backup on  weekly overview

    globals-only.7z 7448auth.7z 743

Comment: @sCHween, Sorry, I somehow dropped the formatting from `printf`. Try now with the updated answer.

Comment: @sCHween, any luck with this?